# How to change the content offset of a UICollectionView simultaneously?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal scrollable collectionView with two cells that take up the screen. Inside those cells is an embedded collection view that scrolls vertically. Is there a way for me to scroll the vertical CV inside the first cell, while using its ContentOffset to scroll the vertical CV in the second cell?

Here's how I'm trying to accomplish it:

```
let scrollView = notification.userInfo!["scrollView"] as! UICollectionView
if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 250.0 {
   childViewControllerForPosts.collectionViewForGroups?.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y), animated: false)

        self.topVerticalConstraint?.constant = -scrollView.contentOffset.y

    }
    else {

        if self.topVerticalConstraint?.constant > -250 {
            // Make sure it stays at -250
            self.topVerticalConstraint?.constant = -250
        }

    }
```

The `FeedCell` would be the main collection view (which horizontally scrolls) that contains the vertical scrolling collection view. I'm trying to access the second one to change the vertical contentOffset when I scroll the one in first one.

Here's how I'm trying to save the variable that should contain the second main collection view:

`collectionViewForGroups = collectionView(collectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forItem: 1, inSection: 0)) as? FeedCell`

EDIT:
Note that when I scroll horizontally, the vertical scroll view didn't change. But I want it to change with the one I just scrolled in the gif. If I were to scroll the 2nd vertical collection view, the UIView above will reappear because the topLayConstraint changes due to the vertical contentOffset change.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you access second collectionView? isn't it working? Whats problem there?

Comment: I have two vertical collection views that scroll vertically. One is in a main collection view cell (which scrolls horizontally), and the other one is in the second main collection view cell. I want to make sure that when I scroll the first one vertical collection view, the second one also scrolls with the first. I can scroll the first vertical CV, but when I scroll horizontally and see the second vertical CV, its still in the same position, as seen in the GIF, which I added just now for you.

Comment: You need to store contentOffset of first collectionView and apply it to second collectionView when its displayed. There is no other way.

Comment: Dipen, would you like to discuss this through email? I'm getting kinda desperate to solve this lol

Comment: Not today but tomorrow for sure. My email is dips_panchasara221@yahoo.co.in we can discuss there. Thanks